# ONT Showing “Not Connected” When Using Media Converter to Connect the WAN interface to an Ethernet Network

Tags: ethernet, troubleshooting, fiber

I am using a media converter to connect a ZXHN F660 ONT to an Ethernet Network. The fiber mode, wavelengths, and upstream/downstream match. The WAN (GPON) interface is defined as an IPv4 interface rather than the original PPPoE. Still, the WAN interface shows "Not Connected". The ONT specifications, the media converter specifications, the SFP specifications, and the patch cord specifications are below. Any suggestions?

http://enterprise.zte.com.cn/en/products/network_lnfrastructure/BroadbandAccess/xpononu/201708/t20170802_464902.html
https://www.sfpcables.com/10-100-1000m-gigabit-fiber-media-converter-single-mode-rj45-to-sfp-20km
https://www.sfpcables.com/1000base-sfp-transceiver-abl43-24-20
https://sale.sfpcables.com/sc-to-lc-singlemode-simplex-os2-9-125

Comment: Not sure where the media converter comes into play. In my setup it's fibre from my isp, to ont to Ethernet. No media converter needed. The media converter would be needed for fibre ethernet to copper... But not when using a ont the usual way

Comment: Also I suspect the protocol they use - gpon may not be the same as optical Ethernet

Comment: I am using a media converter because I am connecting the WAN interface to an Ethernet network.  The WAN interface of an ONT is fiber and needs a media converter to act as a bridge.

Comment: In other words, I am not using it in the usual way.  I am using it in a lab.  :)

Comment: The wan interface may be a different protocol then

Comment: Yes.  After reading your message, I thought that I might have to tweak those settings.  OK.  I will give it a shot later this week.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

While they're both fibre optic, GPON is a different protocol and designed differently from optical Ethernet. They use different modules ([fibre supply's wiki seems a great source of information](https://community.fs.com/blog/basic-knowledge-about-gpon-sfp-transceivers.html) ) on either end and optical splitters for connecting one line to many clients.

It's not working cause they are probably not interoperable. I'm not sure though if an olt sfp in your optical converter would do the trick though